# Develop both 32 and 64bit OpenGL app on Ubuntu

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, mesa

I want to develop both 32 and 64bit lib, which depends on OpenGL(mesa) on Ubuntu (64-bit).

However it seems to be impossible to install both 32 and 64bit version of libgl1-mesa-dev.
When I `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`, it install the 64-bit version. After that I `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev:i386`, it will install 32-bit version but will uninstall the 64-bit one.

Is it possible to let 32 and 64bit version of libgl1-mesa-dev co-exist? Or any alternative method I can try?

Comment: I am not sure, but is it possbile that the 64-bit version got installed also the 32-bit binaries of OpenGL?

Comment: No, I cannot build my app in 32-bit (failed in linking stage) when the 64-bit version of mesa is installed.

Comment: This is a bug, as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/949606)

Answer (score 0):

Download and compile Mesa [from the source code](http://www.mesa3d.org/) if your package manager gives you problems.

By the way you can always use whetever OpenGL you want according to your hardware configuration or OS platform.